# SNOPT Build Issue with Drake

Tags: drake

After downloading and setting paths for SNOPT's license and packages (downloaded from [https://ccom.ucsd.edu/~optimizers/downloads/](https://ccom.ucsd.edu/%7Eoptimizers/downloads/)), I'm getting a stream of errors when building:

```
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'snopt':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/user/test_ws/src/drake/tools/workspace/snopt/repository.bzl", line 193, column 29, in _impl
                _setup_local_archive(repo_ctx, snopt_path)
        File "/home/user/test_ws/src/drake/tools/workspace/snopt/repository.bzl", line 155, column 35, in _setup_local_archive
                error = _extract_local_archive(repo_ctx, snopt_path)
        File "/home/user/test_ws/src/drake/tools/workspace/snopt/repository.bzl", line 136, column 10, in _extract_local_archive
                patch(repo_ctx)
        File "/home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/28ae928fce52b17ea503ec9c423e6cfc/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/utils.bzl", line 180, column 21, in patch
                fail("Error applying patch %s:\n%s%s" %
Error in fail: Error applying patch //tools/workspace/snopt:snopt-openmp.patch:
can't find file to patch at input line 6
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|We patch the snopt_interface to mark the character workspace as threadprivate.
|Otherwise, solving distinct problems in multiple threads still has data races.
|
|--- interfaces/src/snopt_wrapper.f90.orig      2019-01-28 17:12:02.415160931 -0500
|+++ interfaces/src/snopt_wrapper.f90   2019-01-28 17:10:52.610244839 -0500
```

What was the expected site to download SNOPT from?

[UPDATE]

I've cloned the [snopt-interface repo](https://github.com/snopt/snopt-interface) and renamed it as `interfaces`. Overall, my extracted snopt folder looks like the following:

```
snopt/
    libsnopt7_cpp.so
    libsnopt7_cpp.a
    ...
    interfaces/
        ...
        src/
            snopt_wrapper.f90
            ...
```

I'm now getting an error:

```
Error in fail: Error applying patch //tools/workspace/snopt:snopt-openmp.patch:
patching file interfaces/src/snopt_wrapper.f90
Hunk #1 FAILED at 192.
```

[UPDATE]

After checking out to different versions of snopt-interfaces ([in fact your most recent commit](https://github.com/snopt/snopt-interface/commit/9cd5d6b699b1a523fa260ba3055572616e364b9e)), I'm now getting errors that seem to be caused by differences between the SNOPT binaries and drake's SnoptSovler class. I've emailed UCSD about providing SNOPT version 7.4, and they responded that they can only provide drake with the newest SNOPT 7.7.

```
solvers/snopt_solver.cc: In lambda function:
solvers/snopt_solver.cc:1071:38: error: too many arguments to function
 1071 |         storage.rw(), storage.lenrw());
      |                                      ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking more carefully now, I see that SNOPT 7.4 and 7.6 should have the same file structure in any case.  Maybe the problem is with the file layout within the SNOPT archive?

Drake expects the `snopt-VERSION.tar.gz` to contain pathnames like `snopt-VERSION/interfaces/src/snopt_wrapper.f90`, i.e., there is a top-level, version-number-related subdirectory.  If your archive did not have a top-level directory, the build would show the failure you posted.

That directory is removed with the "strip-components" line [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/50ad42def05240ad45875dc4137e7a1bf128c04c/tools/workspace/snopt/repository.bzl#L126-L132), at which point Drake expects to see a file named `interfaces/src/snopt_wrapper.f90` in the archive.

If your archive had a different layout, that could be the problem.

Comment: I've updated my original question.

Comment: Hi @jwnimmer-tri, I think the differences between SNOPT 7.7 and what Drake currently supports are causing the issues I mentioned above, so the option of specifying my own, local SNOPT path will take a while to fix. The docs mention a second alternative, which is using Drake's "private RobotLocomotion/snopt". Could you give me access to that?

Comment: No, sorry; the MIT group's SNOPT archive is only open to the MIT lab people.

Answer (score 0):

Drake currently expects to use `SNOPT 7.4-1.1`, which is older that the latest release.  Hopefully the download site still offers that version.  I expect that any 7.4 series should work.

This is hinted at by the documentation at https://drake.mit.edu/bazel.html ("7.4") but isn't completely clear.

It's *possible* that a different version of SNOPT might work by either manually adjusting that patch file, or by commenting it out at [in workspace rule](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/50ad42def05240ad45875dc4137e7a1bf128c04c/tools/workspace/snopt/repository.bzl#L220), but no guarantees.

Comment: I see, will try that and get back to you. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: Also, Drake expects SNOPT to be provided in _zipped source code form_ (where you buy a license).  The free "student version" one where SNOPT comes as a binary library + header is not supported.  Perhaps you'd be better off using a [pre-compiled Drake release](https://drake.mit.edu/installation.html) instead of building from source.