# AddMinimumDistanceConstraint with No Proximity Geometries Still Fails Inverse Kinematics

Tags: drake

I'm trying to include a self-collision avoidance constraint while solving IK. I'm using NLOPT as the solver, and IK without any MinimumDistanceConstraint works well. However, MinimumDistanceConstraint causes the same IK problem to fail. I've visually verified that the solution is feasible. Even when removing the Proximity role of all geometry bodies, IK still fails.

Does anyone have tips on debugging IK failures?
What could be the issue here?

```
  string sdf_filepath = "my_robot.sdf";
  float timestep = 0.0;
  drake::systems::DiagramBuilder<double> builder;
  drake::multibody::MultibodyPlant<double>* plant{};
  drake::geometry::SceneGraph<double>* scene_graph{};
  std::tie(plant, scene_graph) = drake::multibody::AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(&builder, timestep);
  plant->set_name("plant");
  scene_graph->set_name("scene_graph");
  drake::multibody::Parser parser(plant, scene_graph);

  const auto robot_model_index = parser.AddModelFromFile(sdf_filepath, "robot");

  plant->Finalize();

  auto diagram = builder.Build();
  auto diagram_context= diagram->CreateDefaultContext();
  auto plant_context = &(diagram->GetMutableSubsystemContext(*plant,
  diagram_context.get()));

  auto all_geom_ids = inspector.GetAllGeometryIds();
  for (const auto& geom_id : all_geom_ids) {
    const auto source_id = inspector.GetOwningSourceId(geom_id);  // NOTE: custom function making a private function public 
    scene_graph->RemoveRole(source_id, geom_id,
        drake::geometry::Role::kProximity);
  }

  // Verified this is empty
  auto collision_pairs = inspector.GetCollisionCandidates();

  drake::multibody::InverseKinematics ik_solver(*plant, plant_context, with_joint_limits);
  float min_distance = 0.1;  // padding distance
  ik_solver.AddMinimumDistanceConstraint(min_distance);
  
  // Solve IK
  ..... // setting pos/ori constraints for EE, solver parameters
  solver_id = drake::solvers::NloptSolver::id();
  std::optional<drake::solvers::SolverId> solver_id_optional = solver_id;
  auto result = drake::solvers::Solve(ik_solver.prog(), solver_id_optional);  // custom change: force NLOPT to be used

  // solver_results.status is 4, but result.is_success() is False, ProgramAttributesSatisfied(ik_solver.prog) is True
  auto solver_results = result.get_solver_details<drake::solvers::NloptSolver>();
```

Comment: May I ask why you force to use NLOPT? Have you tried other solvers like IPOPT and SNOPT?

Comment: Sure. I have tried using IPOPT (Drake default selects this actually) and it performs worse than NLOPT (low success rate around 80%). I have tried to use SNOPT, but there are various issues ([here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/8836) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73899685/snopt-build-issue-with-drake/73901831?noredirect=1#comment130512011_73901831)). I'm also confused why Drake's GurobiSolver reports that GenericConstraints are not supported even though they claim approximate the nonlinear constraints via piecewise linear functions.

Comment: Our Drake wrapper doesn't convert GenericConstraints to piecewise linear functions in Gurobi.

Comment: Is it possible that you could share your `my_robot.sdf` file so that I can reproduce the error?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Gurobi itself, not Drake for the constraint approximation. Yes, I believe I would need to share via email privately though.

Comment: Could you send me the sdf file to hongkai.dai@tri.global? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My colleague Sean Curtis figured out the problem

The `plant_context` is constructed BEFORE removing the collision geometries. So this `plant_context` doesn't know that the collision geometries are removed, hence it still computes the distance for all pairs as if the proximity geometries were still there.

So there are two solutions:

1. Put the for loop with `RemoveRole` BEFORE creating the `diagram_context`
2. Alternatively, you can call `RemoveRole(scene_graph_context,...)` as in this [function](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_scene_graph.html#ae44aad4ae777364606768c0c8b6a98bc), so the code looks like

```cc
auto scene_graph_context = scene_graph.GetMyMutableContextFromRoot(diagram_context);
for (const auto& geom_id : all_geom_ids) {
    const auto source_id = inspector.GetOwningSourceId(geom_id);  // NOTE: custom function making a private function public 
    scene_graph->RemoveRole(scene_graph_context, source_id, geom_id,
        drake::geometry::Role::kProximity);
  }
```

Comment: Wow that is insane! This was pretty confusing. Does [this comment](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/f0d86e28b8922649642987c5fcb67117d0a01e67/geometry/scene_graph.h#L222) basically summarize this issue? Which of the two solutions would you advise for future scenarios, where say plant and scene_graph are class members, and I want to perform IK/trajopt with geometries that could have been modified before?

Comment: This is a common pitfall. My colleague is going to add this to the debugging tips in Drake.

Comment: I would create the context just before I actually use it in IK/trajopt.