# Building drake with trial version snopt

Tags: drake

I've studied a [similar ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73899685/snopt-build-issue-with-drake), that's marked resolved, where the person who asked, however, didn't write that they managed to build Drake with SNOPT.

I am presently trying to perform the same feat, also having a hard time.

**I.** Presently my compilation error comes from an API mismatch between `snopt.h` from [snopt-interfaces](https://github.com/snopt/snopt-interface/blob/master/include/snopt.h) and `drake/solvers/snopt_solver.cc`:

```
solvers/snopt_solver.cc: In instantiation of 'static void {anonymous}::SnoptImpl<false>::sninit(const char*, int, int, Int*, int, double*, int) [with Int = int]':
solvers/snopt_solver.cc:1132:16:   required from here
solvers/snopt_solver.cc:144:23: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
  144 |     ::f_sninit(name, &len, &iprint, &summOn, iw, &leniw, rw, &lenrw);
      |                       ^~~
      |                       |
      |                       int*
solvers/snopt_solver.cc:144:29: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
  144 |     ::f_sninit(name, &len, &iprint, &summOn, iw, &leniw, rw, &lenrw);
      |                             ^~~~~~
      |                             |
      |                             int*
solvers/snopt_solver.cc:144:38: error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'const char*'
  144 |     ::f_sninit(name, &len, &iprint, &summOn, iw, &leniw, rw, &lenrw);
      |                                      ^~~~~~
      |                                      |
      |                                      int*
```

These issues are not easy to debug as I've learned that one is supposed to copy-paste certain files from [snopt-interface](https://github.com/snopt/snopt-interface) repository only from the stackoverflow question linked above.
Also, in my particular case, none release tags seem to have the interface that matches.

**II.**  But a bigger issue for my case stems from a brief comment that I've seen in the adjacent question:

> Also, Drake expects SNOPT to be provided in zipped source code form (where you buy a license). The free "student version" one where SNOPT comes as a binary library + header is not supported.

My SNOPT distribution comes in exactly that form: a trial version, which consists of prebuilt binaries, headers and a license file.
I'm not 100% positive, but it looks like the version is `SNOPT 7.2-12.2 (Jul 2013)` (if that's important).

Using the prebuilt Drake is not a option for me, because I work in a custom branch.
And optimization problems that I try to run (similar to those from [Robotic Manipulation course](https://manipulation.mit.edu/trajectories.html)) diverge when using INOPT, but converge within deepnote environment.

Do you think that it's a terrible amount of work to support prebuilt SNOPT in Drake?
If you could write up a small instruction, I could volunteer a PR. I we do so, I could also provide a markdown patch for the [doc](https://drake.mit.edu/bazel.html) to capture all build steps explicitly.

I guess, the first question about the interface mismatches is only relevant if you see any way forward with this case.

Thank you for help!

Comment: >Also, Drake expects SNOPT to be provided in zipped source code form (where you buy a license)

Their official site doesn't even state the cost of the paid license. In my experience, that usually means, that the cost is at a level prohibitive for individual.

Comment: @jwnimmer-tri Sir, I'll tag you here because I've quoted your comment from another related question. Thank you for your time.

Comment: See https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/8836 for past discussion about using precompiled snopt.  See https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/17609 about a possible downgrade to 7.2.
("Do you think that it's a terrible amount of work to support prebuilt SNOPT in Drake?")
Actually I don't have any idea one way or another.
("Using the prebuilt Drake is not a option for me, because I work in a custom branch.")
This seems like a more worthwhile problem to try to fix.